# Is it true that $\Phi_n(2)$ has a divisor of the form $kn+1$ for all $n\neq 6$?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Let $\Phi_n(x)$ be the $n$ th cyclotomic polynomial.  I've checked the values of $\Phi_n(2)$ for some small  $n\geq 2$ and noticed that there is always a divisor of  $\Phi_n(2)$   of the form $kn+1$ (regardless of  $\Phi_n(2)$ being a prime or not)  with the only exception of $n=6$. Does anyone know any counterexample  to this or a proof for its validity?

Comment: To begin with, does $2^n-1$ always have a divisor of this form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\Phi_{21}(2)$ is a multiple of 7.  The actual divisibility criterion can be found in notes of G. J. O. Jameson mentioned here  [Cyclotomic polynomials: $\Phi_n(p)$ is like $p^{\phi(n)}$ for big enough $p$, right?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/221357) .  In particular, non-Zsigmondy primes $q$ divide $\Phi_n(a)$ only if they are coprime to $a$ and $n=mq^k$ where m is the order of $a \bmod q$.

The original question is answered by Zsigmondy and Bang, and the notes of Jameson give a nice brief account.  Yes, with the exceptions noted, such prime divisors exist.

Gerhard "Divisibility Is Not So Simple" Paseman, 2016.04.27.

Comment: Another recent paper which may be of interest is Granville's http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6306 , which contains references to further generalizations/relations of Zsigmondy's theorem.  Gerhard "Where One Learns Primitive Factors" Paseman, 2016.04.27.

Comment: Thanks for the link http://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/cyp.pdf . Theorem 2.5 there answers my question, hence the question asked by @Alex. In fact not only one but all divisors of $\Phi_n(2)$ greater than $n$ are of the form $kn+1$ according to that theorem. It also characterizes the divisors less than $n$. Actually my question is $a=2$ case of that theorem.

Answer (score 3):

In point of fact, it is well-known that if $p$ is a prime number and $a, n$ are integers that are not divisible by $p$, then $p \mid \Phi_{n}(a)$ implies $p\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$.

Comment: Can't be iff; there are infinitely many primes $p\equiv1\bmod n$, and they can't all divide $\Phi_n(a)$. Unless those dots at the end are hiding something.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: You are absolutely right!